# Multiple usernames as admin php

Tags: php

I have a simple php script that check for the username "admin" and makes certain pages available to that user. I want to add multiple users to that admin "role" is that possible? Here is the code:

```
$okFiles = array('login.php', 'signup.php', 'password_reset.php', 'auto_update_scores.php', 'getHtmlScores.php');
if (!in_array(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), $okFiles) && (empty($_SESSION['logged']) || $_SESSION['logged'] !== 'yes')) {
header( 'Location: login.php' ) ;
} else {
$user = $login->get_user($_SESSION['loggedInUser']);
$adminUser = $login->get_user('admin');
}

$isAdmin = 0;
if ($_SESSION['loggedInUser'] === 'admin' && $_SESSION['logged'] === 'yes') {
$isAdmin = 1;
}
```

So, say I wanted the usernames admin, mark, and jones to be admins... how would I change the above code to do that?

Comment: You're best to create a column in DB called "admin" with a Y or N option and set the appropriate usernames to one of those, then you'd use a WHERE clause I.e.: `WHERE admin = 'Y'` for example. It could be anything really, yet you get the general idea.

Comment: I thought about that but I'm not sure I know enough to write it. i figured I could manually add the names to this existing script somehow.

Comment: I wouldn't do that, I would use an SQL method and not a SESSIONS method. It's best to have your users permissions inside a DB table; but that's just me.

Comment: Well crap, I wouldn't know where to start on that one. Thanks though.

Comment: You're welcome. Look into it though, it's well worth the effort.

Comment: Can someone take this off hold and remove the downvote? The guy that answered (J.J.) understood what I was asking just fine... not sure what everyone else's deal is.

Comment: You should flag the question instead of posting a comment. As for the downvote, there's nothing you can do about that. Whoever downvoted had a reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not necessarily the best way to do things, but as a very simple means of accomplishing this, you could implement an array of 'admin' users and then check the supplied username against that array for a match. I would also recommend converting the supplied username to lowercase to avoid case sensitivity in the username (ex. comparing ADMIN vs admin).

```
$adminUsers = array('admin','mark','jones');
$isAdmin = 0;
if (in_array(strtolower($_SESSION['loggedInUser']), $adminUsers) && $_SESSION['logged'] === 'yes') {
    $isAdmin = 1;
}
```

Comment: This does exactly what I needed and asked for, thank you. I had to add the } bracket back in before $isAdmin = 0 , and it worked perfectly. Thank you so much.